# I want to set the width of picture as two columns of my article of three columns

Tags: floats, multicol

I'm writing an article with three columns, and I use the code

```
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\end{multicols}
```

Now I want to insert a picture which occupies two columns size. How could I accomplish it?

Comment: Could you please insert a MWE which shows what you have tried?  EDIT: Could you also make your title more clear.  "Picture occupies two columns" implies, the code you tried already worked for you, which I guess is not the case.

Comment: I'm sorry to fail to make my problem clear. How about now?

Comment: Please be (still) more specific: Should the picture span columns 1 and 2, or should it span columns 2 and 3?

Comment: @Zhang: nothing to be sorry.  We are just trying to help you as specific as we can.  But to do so, we have to understand your problem and therefor you must describe your problem as clear as possible.  Can you insert your MWE?

Comment: the picture should span column 2 and 3, but later I will meet the situation of 1 and 2.

Answer (score 2):

`multicol` doesn't support floats but you can always position an image by hand, leaving space in the spanned columns;

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{multicol}

\def\a{\stepcounter{enumi}\Roman{enumi}: \roman{enumi} one two three (\theenumi) four five. }
\def\b{\a\a Green yellow black white. \a\a\a}
\def\c{\b\b\par Apple pear orange. \b\par}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{3}
\c\b\b

\rlap{\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr2\columnwidth+\columnsep}
\centering
\begin{picture}(100,100)
\put(50,95){\line(1,-3){25}}
\put(50,95){\line(-1,-3){25}}
\put(25,20){\line(1,0){50}}
\put(45,20){\line(0,-1){15}}
\put(55,20){\line(0,-1){15}}
\thicklines
\put(20,5){\line(1,0){60}}
\end{picture}
\captionof{figure}{A Christmas Tree}
\end{minipage}}

\c
\columnbreak
\vspace*{11\baselineskip}\c\c
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does this code support Chinese font if I replace `article` by `ctexart`?

Comment: @Zhang yes of course, it is just positioning the image by hand and adding the vspace "by eye" where needed to leave space in the third column.